# How to export result into the same excel sheet?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to extract active accounts whose attribute is empty in 3 organizational units. However, I would like the results to be displayed in the same excel file. Is it possible to help me with this?

```
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$path = "c:\temp\empty_attributes.xlsx"

$OU1 = "OU=Accounts,DC=com,DC=contoso"
$OU2 = "OU=TestAccounts,DC=com,DC=contoso"
$OU3 = "OU=Users,DC=com,DC=contoso"

Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(employeeNumber -like "*") -and (Enabled -eq "True") }  -SearchBase $OU1 -Properties * | select name, samaccountname, employeeNumber | Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2


Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(employeeNumber -like "*") -and (Enabled -eq "True") }  -SearchBase $OU2 -Properties * | select name, samaccountname, employeeNumber | Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2


Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(employeeNumber -like "*") -and (Enabled -eq "True") }  -SearchBase $OU3 -Properties * | select name, samaccountname, employeeNumber | Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just process it in one pipeline, instead of having multiple variables for each Organizational Unit, store them all in one array and then loop over it:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$path = "c:\temp\empty_attributes.xlsx"

$OUs = @(
    "OU=Accounts,DC=com,DC=contoso"
    "OU=TestAccounts,DC=com,DC=contoso"
    "OU=Users,DC=com,DC=contoso"
)

$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!employeeNumber=*))'
    Properties = 'employeeNumber'
}

$OUs | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser @params -SearchBase $_ } |
    Select-Object name, samaccountname, employeeNumber |
    Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2
```

You also need to consider stop using `-Properties *` and use only specific attributes you need to query, otherwise your query will be very inefficient.